# Summarizing table based on 2 columns using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, statistics, summarizing

I got a shapefile that has the landuse and the area of every single piece of ground near a specific road. Like this:

[image]

I want to summarize all landuse areas of near each road in one row. Like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Try pivot table in Excel

Comment: Does the Summary Statistics tool in ArcMap do what you require?  See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it in ArcMap.

1. Make a new field that concatenates '**road**' + '**landuse**', I'll call it '**road_landuse_concat**'
2. This can be done by using the Field Calculator on your new field with the operation "road" + "landuse" and running the tool.
3. Once that '**road_landuse_concat**' is created and populated, right click on the field in the attribute table, and select 'Summarize...'
4. In the Summarize menu, scroll to the 'area' field, and check the box for 'Sum'
5. Specify the location of your output table, and run the Summarize tool.

However it will not give you separate fields for residential, park, and commercial, but it will summarize the landuse areas for each combination of unique road-landuse combination, which it appears you're looking for. A pivot table in excel can get you something closer to your second picture, but that means doing this outside of ArcGIS.